# How to parse a Json received via TCP/IP?

Tags: c#, json, tcp

I received an output string from a camera which has a default format:`<Ticket><length>CR LF <Ticket><content>CR LF`

Example of this format:`<ticket=0010>L<length>CR LF<ticket=0010><unique message ID>:<JSON content>CR LF`

Result:`0010L000000045\r\n0010000500000:{"ID": 1034160761,"Index":1,"Name": "Pos 1"}\r\n`

So basically, my output string has some preliminary objects and then a JSON string. 
After I start my client-side and connect it to the camera which runs the server-side of the TCP/IP, I received the output string of the camera which was this: (0000L000000114
0000, 20)
(24.380417;13.144794;62.600601;51.364979;+0.491;;59.664135;77.126488;97.884323;115.346687;+0.464;;
, 99)
Here I always used to get two string, first string, if compared with default format, has:

```
<Ticket><length>CR LF <Ticket>
```

and the second string which is of 99 bytes should be a JSON content according to the default format. 
In the second string, the string indicates x,y, and z coordinates of two different regions of interest which I want in integer format because the x and y coordinates are of the corner and I want to find that of the center. So, for my application only 2nd string is of interest so I used this code to eliminate the first string:

```
if (readByCount > 30)
                {
                    var output = (new string(buff).TrimEnd('\u0000'), readByCount);
                    Debug.WriteLine(output);}
```

So as the first string was of less than 30 bytes, it was not displayed. I tried splitting the 2nd string first by (;;) and then by (;) and make them of integer format by using code :

```
 public async void ReadDataAsync(TcpClient mClient)
    {
        try
        {
            StreamReader clientStreamReader = new StreamReader(mClient.GetStream());

            char [] buff = new char[1024];
            int readByCount = 0;


            while (true)
            {
                readByCount = await clientStreamReader.ReadAsync(buff, 0, buff.Length);

                Directory.CreateDirectory("Camera o3D1");

                if (readByCount <= 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Disconnected from Server.");
                    mClient.Close();
                    break;
                }
                if (readByCount > 30)
                {
                    var output = new string(buff).TrimEnd('\u0000');
                    Debug.WriteLine(output);
                    var output1 = output.Split(new[] { ";;" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(s => s.Split(';')
                    .Select(i => int.Parse(i)).ToArray()).ToArray();
                    Console.WriteLine(output1);                    
                }

                Array.Clear(buff, 0, buff.Length);
            }


        }
        catch (Exception excp)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(excp.ToString());
        }
    }
```

But I am getting an error saying: Input string was not in correct format.

I tried the above code to split a normal string like 
string text = "3;4;5;6;7;;3;4;5;6;7;;3;4;5;6;7;;3;4;5;6;7;;3;4;5;6;7;;"; 
and I was successful, but it's not working with JSON content. I believe the method which works with normal string won't work with JSON content. What do I have to do to split each component of the JSON and change the data type to an integer so that I can do some maths wit it?

Answer (score 0):

"Input string was not in correct format" is the error generated by "int.Parse(i)" when the input string is not parseable as a valid integer

You are parsing every string returned by the split. One of those strings is"0000L000000114" which cannot be parsed into an integer, hence your error.